# How to reload page after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$('form').submit(function () {
    value = true;
    var schoolName = $('#addSchoolName').val();
    if (schoolName.trim() == '') {
        $('#addSchoolName').addClass('border border-danger');
        value = false;
    }
    if (value) {
      return true;
    }
    else { return false;}
});

$("form").bind('ajax:complete', function () {
    window.location.reload();
});

$('#close').on('click', function () {
    $('#addSchoolName').removeClass('border border-danger');
    $('#addSchoolName').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="modal fade" id="addSchool" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addSchoolTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered cls" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <label class="modal-title" id="addSchoolTitle">Add School Details</label>
            </div>
            <form asp-action="AddNewSchool" asp-controller="School" asp-antiforgery="true" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body form-group row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="Name">School Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="Name" id="addSchoolName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary " id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using form inside modal and submitting that form. I want to reload my page So that after form submission the list behind that modal will update. I do not want to use Ajax call for form submission.

```
 <div  class="modal fade" id="addSchool" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addSchoolTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered cls" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <label class="modal-title" id="addSchoolTitle">Add School Details</label>
            </div>
            <form asp-action="AddNewSchool" asp-controller="School" asp-antiforgery="true" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body form-group row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="Name">School Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="Name" id="addSchoolName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary " id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and write now I am applying this validation on the form.

```
   @section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('form').submit(function () {
            value = true;
            var schoolName = $('#addSchoolName').val();
            if (schoolName.trim() == '') {
                $('#addSchoolName').addClass('border border-danger');
                value = false;
            }
            if (value) {
              return true;
            }
            else { return false;}
        });

        $("form").bind('ajax:complete', function () {
            window.location.reload();
   });

        $('#close').on('click', function () {
            $('#addSchoolName').removeClass('border border-danger');
            $('#addSchoolName').val('');
        });
    </script>
```

I do not wants to use ajax call for form submission, I want to reload the page after submitting the form inside modal so that the list behind that modal will be updated.

Comment: You could redirect the user back to the same page with ASP

Comment: @ThumChoonTat What will be the complete command for that.

Comment: Reload the same page on success using this => `location.reload();`

Comment: how to know that  form is submitted successfuly

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused because by default it should be reloading on the submit function. This is why we use `event.preventDefault` at the end. but if you want there is always `location.reload`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: I am using form inside modal and want to refresh the page behind the modal after successful submission of form inside modal.